# Do Blob properties on entities affect query performance?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to make my mind on whether to store a binary representation of an entity as its Blob property, or whether I better keep the blobs in some separate 'wrapping' class.
Possible impact on memory heap and/or a query execution time are my concerns in the first case, complexity votes against the other one.

I know Blobs are not indexed, i.e. index size is not what I'm worrying about. Also I assume for blobs Datastore puts defaultFetchGroup to false, but does it mean that blobs don't make a difference in queries?

Regards
J. Záruba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone came across this question this is Nick Johnson's response to similar one:
[Improve App Engine performance by reducing entity size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547750/improve-app-engine-performance-by-reducing-entity-size/1548665#1548665)

And the short answer to my question is 'yes'.